# reactjs not showing the live video while using webrtc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create an broadcasting application using mern stack where when one person goes live using webrtc and it has two components i.e. Broadcaster screen and Viewerscreen but i'm unable to see video on the screen the following is my code for broadcaster screen :-

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {Card} from 'reactstrap';
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';

 class Video extends Component {
   constructor(props)
   {
     super(props);
     this.addCandidate=this.addCandidate.bind(this);
     this.addWatcher=this.addWatcher.bind(this);
     this.answerCan=this.answerCan.bind(this);
     this.endBroadcast=this.endBroadcast.bind(this);
   }
    componentWillMount() {
        // chrome polyfill for connection between the local device and a remote peer
         window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        this.props.media(this);
      }
      componentDidMount() {

        this.props.getUserMedia
          .then(stream => this.localVideo.srcObject = this.localStream = stream);
       this.props.socket.on('watcher',this.addWatcher);
      this.props.socket.on('candidate',this.addCandidate);
       this.props.socket.on('bye',this.endBroadcast);
       this.props.socket.on('answer',this.answerCan);
      }
      answerCan(id,description)
      {
          this.props.peerConnections[id].setRemoteDescription(description);
      }
      addWatcher(e,id)
      {

      this.props.peerConnections[id]=this.peerConnection;
        this.peerConnection.addStream(e.stream);
       this.peerConnection.createOffer()
       .then(sdp=>this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp)).then(()=>this.props.socket.emit('offer',this.peerConnection.localDescription))
       this.peerConnection.onicecandidate=(e)=>{
         if(e.candidate)
         {
           this.props.socket.emit('candidate',e.candidate);
         }
       }
      }
      addCandidate(candidate,id)
      {
        this.props.peerConnections[id].addCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
      }
      endBroadcast(id)
      {
        this.props.peerConnections[id] && this.props.peerConnections[id].close();
        delete this.props.peerConnections[id];
           }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="video-section">
                <Card>
                 <video className="local-video" ref={(ref)=>this.localVideo=ref} autoPlay muted></video>
                </Card>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
Video.propTypes = {
    getUserMedia: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    media: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    socket:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    peerConnections:PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }
export default Video
```

and here is the viewer screen code :-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {PropTypes} from 'prop-types';
 class Viewervideo extends Component {
     constructor(props)
     {
         super(props);

     }
     componentWillMount()
     {
        window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        // this.props.media(this);
     }
     componentDidMount()
     {
         this.props.socket.on('offer',this.startVideo);
         this.props.socket.on('candidate',this.addIceCandidate);
         this.props.socket.on('watcher',this.alertWatcher);
         this.props.socket.on('broadcaster',this.alertBroadcaster);
         this.props.socket.on('bye',this.closeBroadcast);
       //  this.props.media(this);
     }
     startVideo(id,description)
     {
         this.peerConnection=new RTCPeerConnection({ 'iceServers': [{
            'urls': ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302']
          }]});
          this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description)
          .then(()=>{this.peerConnection.createAnswer()})
          .then(sdp=>this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdp)).then(()=>{
              this.props.socket.emit('answer',id,this.peerConnection.localDescription);
          });
          this.peerConnection.onaddStream=(e)=>{
              this.localVideo.srcObject=this.localVideo=e.stream;
          }
          this.peerConnection.onicecandidate=(e)=>{
              if(e.candidate)
              {
                  this.props.socket.emit('emit',id,e.candidate)
              }
          }

     }
     addIceCandidate(id,candidate)
     {
         this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)).
         catch(e=>{alert('error oocured'+e)});
     }
     alertWatcher()
     {
         this.props.socket.emit('watcher');
     }
     alertBroadcaster()
     {
         this.props.socket.emit('watcher');
     }
     closeBroadcast()
     {
         this.peerConnection.close();
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <video className="viewer-video" ref={(ref)=>this.localVideo=ref} autoPlay></video>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
Viewervideo.propTypes={
  //  media: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    socket:PropTypes.object.isRequired,
   // peerConnections:PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
export default Viewervideo;
```

can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong and how can i fix that?

Comment: can you clarify which video you are not seeing ? Broadcaster or Viewer ?

Comment: and where is your signaling code ?

Comment: @G-Man i'm getting error at viewer